# Error: not a TIFF file in node.js while using the tiff library to attempt to parse my tif file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, tiff

```js
import tiff from "tiff";
import * as fs from "fs";

async function tiffTest() {
    const file = fs.readFileSync("./file.tif")

    console.log(file);
    const image = tiff.decode(file);

    // get the first IFD block
    const block = image[0];
    const pixels = block.data;

    // let's see what tags apply
    const fields = block.fields;

    console.log(fields);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error.message);
  }
}

// Call the function
tiffTest();
```

When I log the file I get

<Buffer 49 49 2b 00 08 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 13 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4f 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 03 00 01 00 ... 15135590 more bytes> which the 49

xxd file.tif | more

```
00000000: 4949 2b00 0800 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000  II+.............
00000010: 1300 0000 0000 0000 0001 0300 0100 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 4f14 0000 0000 0000 0101 0300  ....O...........
00000030: 0100 0000 0000 0000 f412 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0201 0300 0100 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0301 0300 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0500 0000 0000 0000 0601 0300 0100 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 1501 0300  ................
00000080: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000090: 1c01 0300 0100 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000  ................
000000a0: 0000 0000 3d01 0300 0100 0000 0000 0000  ....=...........
000000b0: 0100 0000 0000 0000 4201 0300 0100 0000  ........B.......
000000c0: 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 4301 0300  ............C...
000000d0: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000e0: 4401 1000 8f01 0000 0000 0000 d807 0000  D...............
000000f0: 0000 0000 4501 0400 8f01 0000 0000 0000  ....E...........
00000100: 9c01 0000 0000 0000 5301 0300 0100 0000  ........S.......
```

49 seems to show that this is a TIFF file because it starts with II and logging the raw data of the file it shows II. I don't know what is going wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated.